# Why cant I change the text on this theme?

Tags: themes, text

I am a noob at website creation, and I have only recently begun to use wordpress. I looked at a bunch of demos online and they have helped, but I a seemingly simple problem.

My problem is that I am using the (free) theme from [here](http://siteorigin.com/theme/pitch/) and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the text inside that blue image. I want to remove "A bold big slider" and the sentence underneath it. But how do I do that?? Its becoming frustrating.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the docs reveals that you can either disable that slider all together, or add your own slides in it which will replace the default text that you see now.

To add your own slides, use the instructions here: http://siteorigin.com/pitch-documentation/content/home-page-slider/

To disable the slider you should probably hunt for the option. I'm guessing that it's under Appearance > Theme Settings: http://siteorigin.com/pitch-documentation/theme-settings/